# How to add any polymer to azobenzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, synthesis, polymers

I want to make a polymer by adding two polymeric substituent groups to azobenzene (I would like only N-azobenzene-N where N is a polymer and repeats). I have been reading about how they make the polymer. The synthetic methods are quite difficult and expensive.

I thought that azobenzene could be obtained as the result of the oxidation of aniline with potassium permanganate, and then see how to polymerize the azobenzene group as a substituent in a polymer already having the monomer.

The simplest synthesis I can find is using
isocyanate oligomer
4-aminoazobenzene=azobenzene
(1,4-diazabicyclo[2.2.2]octane) =DABCO (catalyst)

I do not understand almost anything about the reaction mechanism, and I'm looking for simpler ways to link a polymer chain to azobenzene.

My references:

https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2009/jm/b918130j
https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2008/SM/b805434g ,
https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.1817082116

Comment: And why is inorganic chemistry tag to this question?

Comment: @NilayGhosh I don't know if it's wrong but I think azobenzene polymers use a lot of solid state stuff, like for example inorganic catalysts and things like clousters are needed for some syntheses.

Comment: Interesting that azobenzene may be conjugated and strictly hindered enough not to polymerize without adding in another monomer.